# Average a column while negating a specific value

Tags: vba, excel, average

I have a column in Excel which has turn-around times (TAT) for laboratory testing.  These start at 1 and count up from there.  This alone poses a problem as anything that is logged in, even if it is not tested, get marked as taking time in the lab, automatically setting the TAT to 1... I have an excess of 1s.

I would like to take an average of this column with the stipulation that values of "1" cannot be included (on average, there 3x the number of untested samples to those tested, so the average TAT is heavily skewed).

I don't know where to start with this and I have been unable to find resolution from searching.  Some items I have found search for characters in a string and will also not count numbers which contain a 1 (11-19, 21, etc).

I also want this data to not be deleted; I have tried hiding the data, but the average still includes the values.  Here is the code I'm currently using.

```
Sub Calculate_FP_NS()

If Range("C4") > 0 Then

    Range("C6").Formula = _
        "=Average('IP&FP, NS'!S2:S5000)"

    Else: Range("C6").Value = 0

End If

End Sub
```

Note that my "fail safe" is the If statement (no values on appropriate sheet).  I should never have more than 5000 roww.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
=SUMIF(values,">1",values)/COUNTIF(values,">1")
```

This will give you the average of all `values` (which should be a range) that are greater than 1.

You can do the same thing in VBA just by calling these worksheet functions:

```
Function averageGreaterThanOne(R As Range)
    averageGreaterThanOne = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(R, ">1", R) / _
      Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(R, ">1")
End Function
```

Comment: This resolved my issue, though I had to make one specific change due to VBA... the ">1" had to be "">1"" due to an expected end of statement.  Thank you, Floris; I was not aware of those functions!

Comment: Glad you sorted it out - the code as posted worked for me but sometimes there are localization issues with certain characters...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a VBA solution, it calculates averages without using sum (sums for >5000 rows could exceed bounds of integer datatypes)
Reference: [long running averages](http://invisibleblocks.com/2008/07/30/long-running-averages-without-the-sum-of-preceding-values/)

```
Public Sub SelectiveSum()
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim column As String: column = "A"
    Dim startRow As Long: startRow = 1
    Dim endRow As Long: endRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count
    Dim count As Long: count = 0
    Dim average As Double: average = 0

    'for each value in the range
    For Each v In Range(column & CStr(startRow), _
    column & CStr(endRow)).Value2
        'checks if v can be converted to Double, and that it is not 1
        If v <> "" And CDbl(v) <> 1 Then
            count = count + 1
            'long running average (so you don't have to keep track of the sum of > 5000 rows)
            average = average + (v - average) / count
        End If
    Next v

    'print
    Range(column & (endRow + 2)).value = "The Sum is: " & Round(average, 3)
    MsgBox "The Sum is: " & Round(average, 3)
End Sub
```